# ASP.NET DataGrid, is it possible to disable sorting on specific columns?

Tags: asp.net

is it possible to disable sorting on specific columns?

5 out of 7 columns have to be sortable, two not sortable. The columns are created dynamically in code behind, so I think doing this with mark up is out of the question.

When I say disabled, I'm hoping that the underline wont show on the column header when you mouse over it.

Any help apprciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your datagrid, each column has a sortexpression. If you have the sortexpression to be blank, those columns won't be sortable.

Answer (score 0):

Old problem, but I faced the same problem today. My fast solution is:

```
protected void GvTicketOnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[6].ToolTip = "Full Column Title";
        e.Row.Cells[6].Controls.Clear();
        e.Row.Cells[6].Text = "Column Title";
    }
}
```